# set ip address python

Tags: python, ip, wmi

i use wmi moudle and try to change my own computer IP Address without any success, its seems that there is not any errors in the running but the the ip address didn't changed
i already checked if i have maybe multiple adapters but i have only one

```
import wmi

# Obtain network adaptors configurations
nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

# First network adaptor
try:
    nic = nic_configs[0]
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception("חבר קודם את המחשב למתג!")

# IP address, subnetmask and gateway values should be unicode objects
ip = u'192.168.43.99'
subnetmask = u'255.255.0.0'
gateway = u'15.0.0.254'

# Set IP address, subnetmask and default gateway
# Note: EnableStatic() and SetGateways() methods require *lists* of values to be passed
print nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip],SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
print nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway])
```

output:

```
(-2147024891,)
(67,)
```

EDIT: I think its due its not running under adminstrator, how can i make it to run automatic by adminstrator?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that if i didn't run as administrator it ignore the code, but when i run it as administrator it worked